# How to write a function that returns something of the type `=> Int`?

Tags: scala

I know a function can receive an arg of the type `=> A` as in

```
def add1(x: => Int): Int = {
  x + 1
}
```

But how do you return such a type in a function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Scala `=>` is special syntax that you can use to specify the evaluation strategy of a method—it's not a proper type, and can't be used outside of the context of method application.

One common idiom for defining a value that won't be fully evaluated immediately is to use `() => A`:

```
def thunkInc(i: Int): () => Int = () => { println(i); i + 1 }
```

Unlike with `=> Int`, you need to "call" the thunk to get the value:

```
scala> val ten = thunkInc(9)
ten: () => Int = <function0>

scala> ten
res5: () => Int = <function0>

scala> ten()
9
res6: Int = 10
```

The [cats library](https://github.com/non/cats) also provides an [`Eval`](http://non.github.io/cats/api/#cats.Eval) type that abstracts over evaluation strategies in a more flexible way.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish it, sample code;

```
scala> def funcReturn: () => Unit = () => {println("Returned Function")}
funcReturn: () => Unit

scala> val ret = funcReturn
ret: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> ret()
Returned Function
```

Comment: `=>Unit` and `() => Unit` are different types

Comment: sure but it's closest to what op asking and please downvoter can you explain how this answer different than the @travis's?

Comment: I did't downvote, your answer seems a bit misleading, but in general ok to me, but I'd think Travis answer was accepted because he pointed out the difference and explained it. Given that author asked exactly for `=>T`, it may have been important for him, also `=>T` and `()=>T` differ in their usage, which was explained by the accepted answer as well.

Comment: @Archeg I think other answer better than mine, too. But I just didn't understand the downvote anyway thanks :)